# Can't install Cumulative Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3093266)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Every time I restart it fails to install. I tried changing the registry keys under profile list to my C: drive instead of %systemdrive% as mentioned here.

[Windows 10 Cumulative Updates Failing (On Computer with SSD System Drive + HDD)](https://superuser.com/questions/959895/windows-10-cumulative-updates-failing-on-computer-with-ssd-system-drive-hdd)

I still get the same problem. I would try a few more things but there is no error code it literally just states that it failed..

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here. I'll try to find out why you can't install the update.

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9C233BC6DACA1C1F!3894&authkey=!AHPcp7vzyajKzdg&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: [Download it and try manual install](http://www.softpoint.in/kb3093266-download-offline-installer-windows-10-cumulative-update.html)

Comment: @Moab I tried to do this before. The install is fine but when I restart it says it can't apply the update.

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log, Windows can't create a [hardlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) of the file `PresentationCore.dll` because the destination is not on C:, it is on drive D: (`D:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationCore.dll`)

> 2015-10-10 17:14:15, Error                 CSI    00000008 (F) Error:
>   ResolvePendingTransactions called after poqexec failure (call 1)
>   Status = **STATUS_NOT_SAME_DEVICE**, **Operation = HardLinkFile**, DiagString
>   = [l:414{207}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_presentationcore_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16425_none_b4330ece2aa010d8\PresentationCore.dll,
>   \??\D:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationCore.dll"

and this causes a `STATUS_NOT_SAME_DEVICE` error and Windows stops installing the update.

So you moved the `Program Files` folder from `C:` to `D:` and this is not supported.

Comment: I changed the programdir key to D: so I would have to keep changing location in every installer. Good job and thanks so much!